# Adobe Flex Problems with Deep Linking and IE 10

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, internet-explorer, apache-flex, flex4.6

I am attempting to implement deep linking in my Flex 4.6 app running in FP 11.  The only functionality I am looking for now is for the forward/back button to work.

In Firefox everything works great, but in IE 10 w/o compatibility mode once you hit the back button it stips the #fragmentValue off the url, thus breaking the forward/back functionality.  If I hit forward it will not put the #fragmentValue back on the URL.  If compatibility mode is on everything works fine.

Has anyone gotten this to work correctly?  It really isnt a feasible feature if we cant support IE > 9.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had this problem when used default `history.js` from FlashBuilder.  The problem in logic of browser version definition:

```
if (useragent.indexOf("msie") != -1) {
        browser.ie = true;
        browser.version = parseFloat(useragent.substring(useragent.indexOf('msie') + 4));
        if (browser.version == 8)
        {
            browser.ie = false;
            browser.ie8 = true;
        }
    }
```

So, all IE greater than 8 will be defined as "less than 8"! We changed this to:

```
browser.version >= 8
```

And now it works fine!